# How to go from main to subprogram and run calculations using the jal instruction

Tags: loops, assembly, console, integer, mips

I am working on a program in MIPS assembly that needs to do the following:

1.) Read a series of integers from the console that are entered by the user.

2.) Valid entries are between 10 and 99 (inclusive).

3.) If an entry is invalid, the entry is rejected and an error message is printed to the screen.

4.) Reading stops when a -1 is entered.

5.) After a -1 is entered, the program displays the number of entries, the sum of the entries, and the integer average of the entries.

I have created a main and subprogram template [**here**](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ae3dce09975cc15f0483). As you can see, there in *main* I have put subroutine calls for my five subprograms which you can see come right after *main*. I use *jal* to jump to the specified subprogram where a calculation will be made.

Am I on the right track with my *main* portion at least and the use of *jal*?

I haven't run the program yet because obviously I dont have any code in the subprograms that would perform calculations to do the five specified requirements. By the way, I use QtSpim as my simulator.

Any help and input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The jump *al* saves the return IP address in $ra. So in your subroutine you can return by jumping back to $ra as follow:

```
    ...
    jal sub_routine
    ...      # <- jr $ra returns here

sub_routine:
    ... # do some work
    jr $ra
```

If you need to call another sub-routine, you have to save $ra, ususally on the stack, before calling jal again.

$ra is the last register, so $31.

Source: http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/devel/assembly/mipsabi32.pdf page 3-12

Comment: So in my verifyUserInput_p subprogram I have come up with some pseudocode of what needs to be calculated. You can see what I mean [**here**](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0ca370838509dd28c518).

Comment: Basically what I am trying to implement is if the user's integer input is between 10 and 99 inclusive, then go back up to the subroutine call and ask for another integer. If the user enters an integer that does not fall between 10 and 99 inclusive, then print an error message and ask the user to try again. But, if the user enters a '-1', the program stops running and displays the number of total entries, the sum of all the entries, and the integer average of the entries.

Comment: Yes, that's generally good. Although you probably want to check whether the number was -1 before you print out the error message. Also, if you want to do all those things in sub-routines you'll have push the $ra register on the stack (if I'm correct: mov $ra, ($sp), add $sp, -4, $sp) the pop it later before you jr $ra, obviously.